# Add more properties to ConstraintViolation

Tags: java, hibernate-validator

I am new to using Hibernate validator and apparent I can only get error message and property path from ConstraintViolation.

What I want to do is to provide more information. For e.g. If I am testing a integer's max value where my max limit keeps changing I want to add max value apart from error message and property path :

1. Error message : some error message
2. Max value : 30
3. Property path : some.property.path

   ```
   public boolean isValid(final Integer integer, final ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {

       boolean isValid = true;
       if(integer >= SomeClass.maxValue) {

           context.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();

           context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("some error message")
           .addPropertyNode("some.property.path")
           .addConstraintViolation();

           isValid = false;
           break;

       }
       return isValid;
   }
   ```

Any idea on how to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to use the dynamic payload feature as explained here: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-dynamic-payload in details. For instance:

```java
HibernateConstraintValidatorContext hibernateContext = context.unwrap(
    HibernateConstraintValidatorContext.class
);
hibernateContext.withDynamicPayload( yourAdditionalInformation );
```

In the examples of the documentation, we only include a simple value but you can inject a bean containing all the properties you need.

Note that this is an Hibernate Validator-specific feature (thus the need to unwrap the context to its Hibernate Validator-specific counterpart).

Comment: I'm facing new issues with this. What I needed was to add these dynamic objects for each violation but they get overridden every time. This is because dynamic payload is shared across the entire context and not just one violation. Any idea on how this can be fixed ?